# Lambda policy to access S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-policies

Can anyone advise on this? I'm trying to access an S3 bucket from a lambda function. I have created the following policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
      {
          "Effect": "Allow", 
          "Principal": {
              "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
          }, 
          "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
      }, 
      {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": [
              "s3:GetObject"
          ], 
          "Resource": [
              "arn:aws:s3:::{{ bucketName }}/*"
          ]
      }
  ]
}
```

But this doesn't seems to work. I have got a
Assume Role Policy: MalformedPolicyDocument: Has prohibited field Resource.

We can't merge multiple access is the same policy?

Answer (score 3):

you are mixing `trust policy` and `permission policy` in single. Can't merge these both.

there is difference in between these policies..

```
The assume role policy is the role's trust policy
```

**trust policy** : allowing the role to be assumed, not the role's permissions policy. `Trust policies do not contain a resource element`

r**ole's permissions policy**( access control policy): what permissions the role grants to the assuming entity.

Comment: Ahh thank you. So does that mean that I have to split and attach a policy on the bucket to allow access? So what is the best approach to allow lambda to access S3 bucket?

Comment: @amir you should look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html#permissions-executionrole-api

Comment: hi LostJon. Thank you for the page. I did read it. And I got the assumeRole trust policy from it. However, my point is how to add S3 bucket access? It's not included in the documentation you provided. Is it?